# Sybase Trigger Changes sp_depends Output

Tags: triggers, insert, sybase, cascade

When adding a cascade insert or update trigger to a table in Sybase, the **sp_depends** ([documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc36273_1251/html/sprocs/X55445.htm)) output on the table object changes:

BEFORE:

```
    column     type                      column name
    id         foreign key reference     example
    column_id  foreign key reference     example
    ..         ..                        ..
```

---

AFTER:

```
    object                          type
    dbo.cascade_insert_trigger      trigger
```

Why does that happen? Why are the referential integrity references not displayed anymore?

Comment: Specific version of Sybase would be useful via @@version as could be a bug.

Comment: The version is: Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 25491 SMP SP132